# PowerBI. Two apparently equal calculated measures are actually different. why?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I end up with the following two calculated measures in Power BI which look semantically equal, but each produces a different result. I'd like to understand why. How does Power BI calculate each so they produce different results?

```
measure1 =
VAR var1 =
    CALCULATE ( [measure], table[column_1] = "some value in column 1" )
VAR var2 =
    CALCULATE ( var1, table[column_2] = "some value in column 2" )
RETURN
    var2
```

Literally, copy the RHS of var1 into its value in var2.

```
measure2 =
VAR var2 =
    CALCULATE (
        CALCULATE ( [measure], table[column_1] = "some value in column 1" ),
        table[column_2] = "some value in column 2"
    )
RETURN
    var2
```

The visual I'm using is a matrix in which the rows are `table[column_2]`, don't know if it matters. In whatever case I'd say this two expresions should be equivalent... but they aren't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a variable with `VAR`, that value is treated as a constant when referenced later.

Therefore, in your first measure, `var2` is the same as `var1` since a constant is not changed by adjusting the filter context with CALCULATE.

If instead of defining a temporary variable, you defined `var1` as a separate *measure*, then it would function as you expected it to in your first example.

---

As a side note, you can use multiple conditions rather than nesting CALCULATE functions:

```
measure3 =
CALCULATE (
    [measure],
    table[column_1] = "some value in column 1",
    table[column_2] = "some value in column 2"
)
```