# DAX: please explain why this measure with a variable will not work

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image: DAX question]

hello. this measure will not work.
can you please explain why not?

Comment: Please use text instead of screenshots when sharing code.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64577044

Comment: @AlexisOlson webpage does not allow to copy text from it, so I've used a screenshot instead

Comment: Is this from some online test or something? It's short enough to quickly be transcribed.

Comment: you need to provide more info. there could be any number of reason why...  
what is your data structure? tables, relationships, datatypes. what output do you get? what do you expect to get?

Comment: It's from online test indeed, so there is no more context

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your measure does not work because you are using a variable as the expression parameter of CALCULATE: variables are immutable; that means that once defined the behave like a constant, that means that their value cannot be changed.

Variables are evaluated where they are defined and not where they are referenced; therefore their value is not affected by modified filter context in CALCULATE.

To check your formula use directly the measure instead of the variable

```
Sales Last Year =
CALCULATE(
    [Total Sales],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( CalendarTable[Date] )
)
```

This way the [Total Sales] is evaluated in the filter context altered by `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( CalendarTable[Date] )`

using a variable instead, like in

```
Sales Last Year (wrong) =
VAR Sales = [Total Sales]
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        Sales,
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( CalendarTable[Date] )
    )
```

makes Sales to be evaluated outside `CALCULATE`, using the filter context existing where the measure is evaluated. Assuming that this value is `1000` the following `CALCULATE` expression is equivalent to

```
    CALCULATE(
        1000,
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( CalendarTable[Date] )
    )
```

that will return 1000 whatever the `SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR` is

Comment: could you please explain that again, but in simple terms and with examples? This is a kind of question that I always get wrong from an exam, so my understanding of the material is really poor.

or perhaps share some resources where this is explained in a way that even I can understand?

Comment: I expanded the explanation. A good resource for DAX articles is the site sqlbi.com, where there also is this article about variables in DAX https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/variables-in-dax/