# DAX: please check if I understood the use of Variabes in DAX correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax

can someone please check if my theoretical understanding of variables is correct?

Suppose that I have a table with 2 columns, Condition1 and Condition2.
I want to count the rows for which Condition1 = 4, and Condition2 = Black.

Soppose then that I write a measure called Black, that creates a Table where all rows have Condition2 = "Black". For Example:

```
Black:= FILTER (Table, Condition2 = "Black")
```

And then I write the combined code using variables:

```
Black4_version1 = 
var B = [Black]
return = CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(B),
Condition1 = 4)
```

Then this code will not work because DAX thinks that the variable B is a single number (because it's calling a measure and measure is by default seen as a single value?), even though I have created a measure that should have created a table.

But if I create the table within a variable itself, then DAX will know that it's a table and then it will work?

```
Black4_Version2 = 
var B = FILTER (Table, Condition2 = "Black")
return = CALCULATE(
COUNTROWS(B),
Condition1 = 4)
```

I'm asking this because I want to be 100% sure that I have understood the answer given here: [DAX: please explain why this measure with a variable will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010077/dax-please-explain-why-this-measure-with-a-variable-will-not-work)
also because I have been using variables already at work, so I will need to re-check all the dashboards that I have built and talk to my manager about screwing up a big time. So you could say that my job depends on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are to be considered constants even when they contain a table. In your `Black4_Version2` measure, the `CALCULATE()` doesn't change the `COUNTROWS(B)` result, since it's counting the rows of a constant table and no filtering is happening.

```
Black4_Version2 =
VAR B =
    FILTER(
        Table,
        Condition2 = "Black"
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS( B ),
        Condition1 = 4
    )
```

but you can iterate over a constant table, therefore FILTER works

```
Black4_Version3 =
VAR B =
    FILTER(
        Table,
        Condition2 = "Black"
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            B,
            Condition1 = 4
        )
    )
```

P.S. I used the pseudo-DAX sintax used in the answer, since instead of `Condition1 = 4` a column reference like `Table[Column1] = 4 should be used`

Comment: so a good rule of thumb is that vaariables: 

- can be used to create filtered tables, which then can be used to be iterated over in return statement (so to create a Filter part of the CALCULATE statement)

- cannot be used to replace Expression over which a Filter is applied later, because the Filter will not work even if you use CALCULATE?

@sergiom

Comment: Correct, also variables can be used as filter arguments in calculate expression.

Comment: so if I understand it correctly, I could write a calculation where I 1st calculate a  variable that gives a filtered table (using FILTER), then in same calculation write a 2nd variable that also uses FILTER using the result from 1st var instead of Table. and then write a return statement where I can write an expression that is iterated over the Table that results from Var2?

Comment: yes.maybe there are more efficient solutions, but it would work

Comment: thank you, I think that I understand now (well, maybe not understand, but I now have a rule that I can learn from the top of my head and hopefully the understanding will follow with practice)